# iQuery get specific HTML attribute

Tags: jquery

How to get "Nose Pins" out of this HTML code using iQuery?

```
<li data-value="nose_pins">
   <span class="js_cat_title">
         <a  data-parent="#accordion" href="#nose_pins_stud_style" class=""></a> 
       Nose Pins
   </span>
</li>
```

I tried this:
`$('.category').filter('[data-value="nose_pins"]').children().html();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Please try this one.
```

```js
alert($('.js_cat_title').not('a').get(0).lastChild.nodeValue.trim())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-value="nose_pins">
      <span class="js_cat_title">
         <a  data-parent="#accordion" href="#nose_pins_stud_style" class=""></a> 
       Nose Pins
      </span>
   </li>
```

Comment: what if the anchor has text what will happened?

Comment: then it's display the anchor text value also.. So i have clear anchor value and then get text from span.

Comment: this is not a solution but a work around. what if the user needs the text un anchor and you removed it?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$('[data-value="nose_pins"]').text().trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this,

```
$('.category [data-value="nose_pins"]').text().trim()
```

or

```
$('li[data-value="nose_pins"]').text().trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
alert($('.js_cat_title').not('a').text().trim())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li data-value="nose_pins">
      <span class="js_cat_title">
         <a  data-parent="#accordion" href="#nose_pins_stud_style" class=""></a> 
       Nose Pins
      </span>
   </li>
```

```
$('.category').filter('[data-value="nose_pins"]').children().not('a').first().text();
```